# Unable to install angular 2 dependencies from node?

Tags: node.js, angular

When trying to to install dependencies it is failing with below error:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated angular2-data-table@0.3.9: moved
npm WARN deprecated ng2-idle@1.0.0-alpha.18: Project moved to @ng-idle/core
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 no such package available : @angular/common
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@angular/common' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'wallet-plus'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\anilkumar\Workplace\Walletplus\walletplus2\npm-debug.log
```

Please find the dependencies i'm trying to install

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"angular2-cookie": "^1.2.3",
"angular2-data-table": "^0.3.8",
"angular2-datatable": "^0.4.2",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.11",
"angular2-localstorage": "^0.2.0",
"angular2-uuid": "^1.0.7",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"core-js": "^2.4.0",
"gulp-gzip": "^1.4.0",
"gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
"gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
"merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
"mydatepicker": "0.0.21",
"ng2-file-upload": "^1.0.3",
"ng2-idle": "^1.0.0-alpha.17",
"ng2-page-scroll": "^1.1.1",
"ng2-slimscroll": "^0.8.0",
"npm": "^3.9.6",
"perfect-scrollbar": "^0.6.14",
"primeng": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"primeui": "^4.1.10",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"socket.io-client": "^1.4.5",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"systemjs-builder": "^0.15.23",
"typescript": "^1.9.0-dev.20160614-1.0",
"typings": "^1.4.0",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12"
},
```

I have changed all versions to '*' and tried but same issue.

FYI: node and npm are up to date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try executing these commands one by one => `npm cache clean; npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org; npm update -g`

Comment: In dependencies, try by changing the version to rc.5.